# Make XAMPP Website Accessible

Tags: xampp

I have developed a website using XAMPP, and am having issues with being able to deploy it for use. The main issue I am having is that the server I am operating on is a corporate server, so I cannot configure the router for a static IP address. The goal of this website is to have it accessible by 10 different computers that will write to an access database. What would be the best method to accomplish this? Thanks, any suggestions are greatly appreciated as I am about to lose my mind.

Comment: You need to access from LAN or WAN?

Comment: @LeaTano I need to access from LAN

Comment: So the server has static lan ip. Like 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.z? Thefore you can use the ip directly. If you want to use a domain like server.local you need to setup the internal dns or add it in hosts file. If you dont know how to do it i can explain ot

Comment: If you want to use domain, you need to include the domain in the virtualhost